# eExecuteDataSet for system.data.common.dbCommand?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

I am using system.data.common.dbcommand for database communications but I couldn't find  ExecuteDataSet in it. Probably it is not supported. Please advice is there some way that I can read multiple datatable in one go (my stored procedure will return multiple selects).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading data into a data-set is really the job of a data-adapter, so spin up an appropriate data-adapter and use that to load the data. You can also use `dataSet.Load(reader)`.

However, please consider: are data-sets really the best metaphor for what you are doing?

Comment: Marc in my situation it is best, as I am looking for results of 3 select statements in one go. What you say is there any better ?

Comment: @user576510 I'm heavily biased, but I'd use dapper / `QueryMultiple()` and `Read<T>()` per grid; LINQ-to-SQL can also handle mapping multiple results to objects

Answer (score 0):

```
public DataSet ExecuteDataSet(string procName,
        params IDataParameter[] procParams)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd;
        return ExecuteDataSet(out cmd, procName, procParams);
    }


    public DataSet ExecuteDataSet(out SqlCommand cmd, string procName,
        params IDataParameter[] procParams)
    {
        SqlConnection cnx = null;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        cmd = null;

        try
        {
            //Setup command object
            cmd = new SqlCommand(procName);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            if (procParams != null)
            {
                for (int index = 0; index < procParams.Length; index++)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(procParams[index]);
                }
            }
            da.SelectCommand = (SqlCommand)cmd;
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.Write(da.SelectCommand);
            //Determine the transaction owner and process accordingly
            if (_isOwner)
            {
                cnx = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
                cmd.Connection = cnx;
                cnx.Open();
            }
            else
            {
                cmd.Connection = _txn.Connection;
                cmd.Transaction = _txn;
            }

            //Fill the dataset
            da.Fill(ds);
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (da != null) da.Dispose();
            if (cmd != null) cmd.Dispose();
            if (_isOwner)
            {
                cnx.Dispose(); //Implicitly calls cnx.Close()
            }`enter code here`
        }
        return ds;
    }
```

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation to your code how it works and how it answers the OP's question.